# Multithreading in Java query

Tags: java, multithreading

just a quick one however a fair amount of code just to give context.

So basically I am making an 'ATM' system replica, here is my code:

```
// BANK ACCOUNT CLASS
public class BankAccount {

    private double balance;

    public BankAccount(double bal) {
        balance = bal;
    }

    public synchronized double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public synchronized void deposit(double amt) {
        double bal = balance;
        bal = bal + amt;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            System.err.println(ie.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("After deposit balance = £" + bal);
        balance = bal;
        notify();
    }

    public synchronized void withdraw(double amt) {
        while (balance < amt) {
            try {
                wait(); // wait for funds
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                System.err.println(ie.getMessage());
            }
        }
        double bal = balance;
        bal = bal - amt;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            System.err.println(ie.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("After withdraw balance = £" + bal);
        balance = bal;
    }
}
```

```
// PRODUCER CLASS

public class Producer extends Thread{
    private BankAccount account;

    public Producer(BankAccount acct) {
        account = acct;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            account.deposit(10);
        }
    }
}
```

```
// CONSUMER CLASS
public class Consumer extends Thread{
    private BankAccount account;

    public Consumer(BankAccount acct) {
        account = acct;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            account.withdraw(10);
        }
    }
}
```

```
// MAIN CLASS
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BankAccount bankAcc = new BankAccount(100);
        Producer timothy = new Producer(bankAcc);
        Consumer sue = new Consumer(bankAcc);

        timothy.start();
        sue.start();

    }
}
```

How it works is the `Producer` class inserts a set sum of money, and the `Consumer` class withdraws a set sum of money, pretty standard.

I am getting this output:

```
After deposit balance = £110.0
After deposit balance = £120.0
After deposit balance = £130.0
After deposit balance = £140.0
After deposit balance = £150.0
After withdraw balance = £140.0
After withdraw balance = £130.0
After withdraw balance = £120.0
After withdraw balance = £110.0
After withdraw balance = £100.0
```

However I am unsure why, I would assume that after one `Producer` loop is run and the `notify()` method is invoked that the `Consumer` object will then be invoked and would print after?

I am new to multithreading so be gentle XD

Comment: I don't think we have full code here.  How did you start out with £100.0 in the account?

Comment: @markspace the bank account instantiates in main with £100 in the constructor

Comment: Please show the code.

Comment: I believe what is happening is the the deposit thread notifies the waiting thread, but then when it exits the monitor, it then immediately locks the bank account object again.  So even though the waiting thread is notified, it always finds the bank account object is locked again.  To fix, try moving the `sleep()` from inside the `synchronized` methods to outside, in the `for` loop in the producer/consumer objects.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what is happening is the the deposit thread notifies the waiting thread, but then when it exits the monitor, it then immediately locks the bank account object again.  So even though the waiting thread is notified, it always finds the bank account object is locked again.  To fix, try moving the `sleep()` from inside the `synchronized` methods to outside, in the `for` loop in the producer/consumer objects.

I made a few changes and it seems to work.  Relying on timing like this (`Thread.sleep()`) is a guaranteed fail in real applications.  It's fine here because it's just a demo.

```
public class Banking {

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      BankAccount bankAcc = new BankAccount( 100 );
      Producer timothy = new Producer( bankAcc );
      Consumer sue = new Consumer( bankAcc );

      timothy.start();
      sue.start();

   }
}

// CONSUMER CLASS
class Consumer extends Thread {

   private BankAccount account;

   public Consumer( BankAccount acct ) {
      account = acct;
   }

   public void run() {
      for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
         try {
            account.withdraw( 10 );
            Thread.sleep( 360 );
         } catch( InterruptedException ie ) {
            // exit
            return;
         }
      }
   }
}

// PRODUCER CLASS
class Producer extends Thread {

   private BankAccount account;

   public Producer( BankAccount acct ) {
      account = acct;
   }

   public void run() {
      for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
         account.deposit( 10 );
         try {
            Thread.sleep( 300 );
         } catch( InterruptedException ie ) {
           // exit
           return;
         }
      }
   }
}

// BANK ACCOUNT CLASS
class BankAccount {

   private double balance;

   public BankAccount( double bal ) {
      balance = bal;
   }

   public synchronized double getBalance() {
      return balance;
   }

   public synchronized void deposit( double amt ) {
      balance += amt;
      System.out.println( "After deposit balance = £" + balance );
      notify();
   }

   public synchronized void withdraw( double amt ) throws InterruptedException {
      while( balance < amt ) 
         wait();
      balance -= amt;
      System.out.println( "After withdraw balance = £" + balance );
   }

}
```

Output of this code:

```
compile-single:
run-single:
After deposit balance = £110.0
After withdraw balance = £100.0
After deposit balance = £110.0
After withdraw balance = £100.0
After deposit balance = £110.0
After withdraw balance = £100.0
After deposit balance = £110.0
After withdraw balance = £100.0
After deposit balance = £110.0
After withdraw balance = £100.0
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

Comment: OMG! The Consumer "exits" after only ONE withdraw...LOL. The author expected that "After deposit..." comes "After Withdraw.." therefore he coded a loop with 5. You got it?